Why does my client-side script is not working on a SSR generated page with Nuxt2?
I'm building a SSR website with Nuxt2 (OK, I know, I have to migrate to Nuxt3 :)) and I'm facing a problem.
When I access a recipe page from another page on the website, the "servings" component does work: I can increment and decrement the number of servings and it adapts the ingredients. In that case I think the page is built by Nuxt because it doesn't make any query.
However, when I access the recipe page directly with its URL, the static page is served from the server (that's good) but the increment and decrement of servings doesn't work. It looks like the page is not "hydrated" with the recipe object.
Would you have any idea on how to make it work ?
Website can be accessed here: https://feature-integration-and-switch-to-pinia--fristouille.netlify.app/
Here's my asyncData function
async asyncData({ params, error, payload, $axios, $config: { queryFunction }, $prismic }) {
    console.log("params", params)
    if (payload) {
        console.log("payload", payload.name);
        let recipe = payload;
        let article = null;

        let compositions = JSON.parse(recipe.compositionsJson);

        if (compositions) {
            compositions.sort((a, b) => b.quantity - a.quantity);
        }

        recipe.compositions = compositions;

        //if there's an associated page in Prismic, retrieve it
        if (recipe.prismicPageId) {
            article = (await $prismic.api.getByID(recipe.prismicPageId));
        }

        return { recipe: recipe, servings: recipe.yield, article: article };
    }
    else {
        //called when recipe page is accessed from another page
        if (params.id) {
            console.log("fetchRecipe", params.id);
            const res = await $axios({
                url: `${queryFunction}?filter=${params.id}`,
                method: "get"
            })
            if (res.data && res.data.length > 0) {
                let recipe = res.data[0];
                let article = null;

                let compositions = JSON.parse(recipe.compositionsJson);

                if (compositions) {
                    compositions.sort((a, b) => b.quantity - a.quantity);
                }

                recipe.compositions = compositions;

                //if there's an associated page in Prismic, retrieve it
                if (recipe.prismicPageId) {
                    article = (await $prismic.api.getByID(recipe.prismicPageId));

                }

                return { recipe: recipe, servings: recipe.yield, article: article };
            }
            else {
                error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
            }
        }
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
    }
}


You have an error on your page suggesting that your code is not isomorphic because you're using some document.querySelector or alike method (that are not available on the server, only on the client). Start troubleshooting this part locally. You could also use this answer to debug further hydration issues.
